# Rewrite rule to replace all + with -

Tags: c#, asp.net

My url contains all`' + '`s like `path/My+Property+Details` but I need to replace all `+` with `'-'`.and make it:

```
path/My-Property-Details.
```

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. Are you using the built-in routing in .net 4? Or are you using a custom module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.Replace(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx), like so:

```
string s = "path/My+Property+Details";
s = s.Replace("+", "-");
```

Don't forget the assignment because a string is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

```
url = url.Replace("+", "-");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string newURL = oldUrl.Replace("+", "-");
```